# C#.NET: Convert Icon to byte[] and back again

Tags: c#, .net

How does one convert between `System.Drawing.Icon` type and `byte[]`?  I'm looking for something simple that can (hopefully) work in .NET2.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You go via a `MemoryStream`, basically:

```
public static byte[] IconToBytes(Icon icon)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        icon.Save(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static Icon BytesToIcon(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return new Icon(ms);
    }
}
```

(Historical note: I wasn't sure whether or not it was safe to dispose of the stream passed to the constructor. It *isn't* safe to do so for `Bitmap`, for example... that holds on to the stream and may read from it later. Apparently it's okay for `Icon` though. I wish MSDN made this clearer...)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the bytes "saved" here are the exact same as the bytes written to a file (so it includes file header, any applicable compression, etc)  not the bytes of the image itself.

Comment: Yes, you could make it a bitmap and extract the array of pixels if you need to.

Comment: Just curious, you wrapped `MemoryStream` neatly in a using-block, why didn't you do equally so in the reverse `BytesToIcon` method? No need to dispose the ms anymore?

Comment: I can verify that Icon reads the stream as soon as it's constructed.

Comment: @BC: Thanks - duly wrapped in a `using` statement now :)

Comment: Thanks!  I had hit a dead end with the Bitmap conversion route.

Answer (score 2):

See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1551fd3b-02b6-4479-852a-dfea4b610c35

Ex (there are multiple ways)

```
private byte[] GetBytes( Icon icon )
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    icon.Save( ms );
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

And:

```
Bitmap bmpIcon = icon.ToBitmap();

using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    bmpIcon.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);        
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: No, don't call `GetBuffer` - that may well have extraneous 0s at the end. `ToArray` is the right call to use.

Comment: Thanks, noted. I really just copied stuff from the link. There are multiple solutions in it. 20 secs on Google :)

Answer (score 1):

... And back again

```
public static Icon IconFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
     using(var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
          return new Icon(ms);
     }
}
```

The Icon class reads from the stream as soon as it's constructed. No harm in closing MS.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I agree that MemoryStream doesn't need a disposal because it doesn't have unmanaged resources... but it reinforces the whole idea of calling dispose when IDisposable is implemented.

Comment: @Hans Passant: not sure what you mean, but perhaps you mean to ask what Dispose does? If a class implements `IDisposable`, it is close to mandatory to wrap it in a using-block. Due to the the lack of multiple inheritance in .NET, certain classes implement `IDisposable` while they technically wouldn't need to. MemoryStream is a class that implements unmanaged code (WaitHandle) and requires that you use `using` or try/finally. It is applied correctly here. In cases where it isn't needed (some implementations of IComponent come to mind), it is often still best to use `using` for clarity.

Comment: PS: if you need an example, see how Jon Skeet corrected his own code after my comment on Dispose.

Comment: Hmya, we'll have to agree about disagreeing about this.  Note that I didn't actually vote it down, it was merely a poke in the eye.